# Parsing Json with a multidimensional array/object. PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, multidimensional-array

I am trying to parse a JSON file for the first time ever and insert the information into my database. The problem is that this object/array is multidimensional, so `$number = stats[0]` is getting values on each level of the array. [This is a link to the JSON file](http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/playerstatsline/20152016/2/SJS/iphone/playerstatsline.json). I want to avoid everthing but the `data:` values that I exploded with PHP. [Here is a link to my output right now](http://52.4.65.161/final_project/statistics.php). If you look at my output, I am only interested in the 8,C,J. Pavelski and 26. Those are the values I want in my database.

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/playerstatsline/20152016/2/SJS/iphone/playerstatsline.json");

$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
      $stats = explode(",", $val);

        $number = $stats[0];
        $position = $stats[1];
        $name = $stats[2];
        $gp = $stats[3];
        $goals = $stats[4];
        $assists = $stats[5];
        $points = $stats[6];
        $plsmns = $stats[7];
        $pim = $stats[8];
        $shots = $stats[9];
        $toi = $stats[10];
        $pp = $stats[11];
        $sh = $stats[12];
        $gwg = $stats[13];
        $ot = $stats[14];


        echo $number."    ".$position."    ".$name."    ".$points."<br />";

/* $query = "INSERT INTO stats2015_2016 ('number','position','name','gp','goals','assists','points','plsmns','pim','shots', 'toi', 'pp', 'sh', 'gwg', 'ot')
             VALUES ('$number','$position','$name','$gp','$goals','$assists','$points','$plsmns','$pim','$shots','$toi','$pp','$sh','$gwg','$ot')";
   $result= $db->query($query); */

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/playerstatsline/20152016/2/SJS/iphone/playerstatsline.json');

$json = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$skaterData = $json['skaterData'];
$goalieData = $json['goalieData'];

foreach($skaterData as $d){
    $sk = explode(',', $d['data']);
    $number = $sk[0];
    $position = $sk[1];
    $name = $sk[2];
    $points = $sk[6];

    echo $number."    ".$position."    ".$name."    ".$points."<br />";
}
```

repeat for goalie data as required

Comment: Thank you! I need to do some JSON practice haha

Comment: Here it is in action. Thanks again! [Link](http://52.4.65.161/final_project/statistics.php)